# Map refcursor of PostgreSQL to java entity using Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am developing a Java application and recently a colleague advised me that my solution will get neater if I use stored procedures for some of my needs. I started reading about them and they really seem promising, but now I am having hard times at making Hibernate map the result returned from such stored procedure to java bean.

Here is the procedure I am trying to get to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wrong_user_answers(testId INTEGER, userId INTEGER) RETURNS refcursor AS $wrong_user_answers$
   DECLARE
      ref refcursor;
   BEGIN
      OPEN ref FOR SELECT ua.*
      FROM t_tests as t
      JOIN t_user_answers as ua on ua.fk_test_id = t.pk_test_id
      WHERE t.pk_test_id = testId and ua.fk_user_id = userId and is_correct(ua) = false;
      RETURN ref;
   END;
   $wrong_user_answers$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here `is_correct(ua)` is another stored procedure I have defined. I have tried this procedure in the PGAdmin and it returns exactly what i expect - refcursor containing user answers.

Here is the java part of the code that I thought should get it all rolling:

The additional annotation (`@NamedNativeQuery`) in the `UserAnswerBean`:

```
@NamedNativeQueries({ 
       @NamedNativeQuery(name = "getWrongUserAnswers", 
                         query = "select wrong_user_answers(:testId, :userId)", 
                         resultClass = UserAnswerBean.class) 
})
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_user_answers")
public class UserAnswerBean {
```

And the code that uses the procedure:

```
Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("getWrongUserAnswers");
query.setParameter("testId", testId);
query.setParameter("userId", userId);
List<UserAnswerBean> answers = query.getResultList();
```

When the code execution attempts on the last line above the following erorr is received:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column name pk_user_answer_id
>   was not found in this ResultSet.
>     org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.findColumn(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2728)
>     org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.getInt(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2589)
>     org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:74)
>     org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
>     org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:267)
>     org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:263)
>     org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
>     org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:338)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:784)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:720)
>     org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:952)

I did not know how to proceed here, I could not find any useful resource in internet. So I assumed that the problem was that I was returning refcursor, not immediately the result of a select, so I changed the stored procedure to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wrong_user_answers(testId INTEGER, userId INTEGER) RETURNS setof record AS $wrong_user_answers$
   SELECT ua.*
      FROM t_tests as t
      JOIN t_user_answers as ua on ua.fk_test_id = t.pk_test_id
      WHERE t.pk_test_id = testId and ua.fk_user_id = userId and is_correct(ua) = false;
   $wrong_user_answers$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Regretfully this did not change the error.

And finally I got to know about the `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` annotation:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "getWrongUserAnswers", 
                           procedureName = "wrong_user_answers", parameters = {
                           @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "testId", type = Integer.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN),
                           @StoredProcedureParameter(name = "userId", type = Integer.class, mode = ParameterMode.IN) },
                           resultClasses = UserAnswerBean.class)
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_user_answers")
public class UserAnswerBean {
```

With the changed java code:

```
    Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("getWrongUserAnswers");
    query.setParameter("testId", testId);
    query.setParameter("userId", userId);
    List<UserAnswerBean> answers = query.getResultList();
```

This did not chnage the error either! Can somebody help me figure out what i am doing wrong?

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if Hibernate played well with refcursors, except perhaps if you do native query `FETCH` statements rather than expecting it to understand them as result sets.

Comment: See my second attempt - no refcursor used there. BTW i think i saw somewhere that hibernate digests refcursors without a trouble, probably playing smart and fetching on them

Comment: It's actually PgJDBC that special-cases refcursor in some contexts, treating it as multiple result sets via the normal jdbc APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fainally I was able to resolve my problem.

I think I might have reported wrong error on the second approach. I basically did not have any luck in the fight with refcursors, but using LANGUAGE sql gave me what I wanted. That is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wrong_user_answers(testId INTEGER, userId INTEGER) 
   RETURNS setof t_user_answers 
   AS $wrong_user_answers$
   SELECT ua.*
      FROM t_tests as t
      JOIN t_user_answers as ua on ua.fk_test_id = t.pk_test_id
      WHERE t.pk_test_id = testId and ua.fk_user_id = userId and is_correct(ua) = false;
   $wrong_user_answers$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

The only difference from before being that I have explicitly specified the return type to be `setof t_user_answers`. The annotations and the java code is exactly as pasted in the question and now everything works for me.

PS: For those wondering I had even harder times to get everything going when I had the result to be no-DB entity, but finally I found [@SqlResultSetMapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html) annotation with [@ConstructorResult](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html) `classes` subannotation to solve the issue (very hard to find solution though).